# как сделать чтобы отправлять на почту код для сброса пароля или подтверждения почты?Laravel

Tags: laravel

как на сайтах или приложениях бывает приходит число типа 523447 каждый раз разное и имеет срок истечения

Чтобы не создавать велосипед может есть какие то известные решения?

Как вариант может создать какую то таблицу

```
authorisation_codes:

id user_id code   type           expires_at
1  2       235487 reset_password 2023-04-12 18:49:07
2  3       557489 verify_email   2023-04-12 20:00:00
```

Когда пользователь к примеру регистрируется создается тут запись с уникальным кодом и отправляется на почту потом этот код проверяется когда запрос на сервер с кодом что был отправлен на почту с тем что в БД

Comment: Посмотри документацию [Email Verification](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/verification), может подойдет тебе

Comment: за эту я знаю это не подойдет для приложений оно отправляет токен ссылкой это только для вебсайта и для жесткого с перезагрузкой страниц